# Youtube/Downloading files eats all my bandwidth in Chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

I'm using Chrome on Ubuntu 15.04 it works fine. Only problem is that when a download is in progress or i'm watching a video it eats all my bandwidth so I cannot open any other website until download finishes.  I  do not have this problem in Firefox, something is wrong with Chrome. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328568/simulate-limited-bandwidth-from-within-chrome

According to Andy Davies, there is a built in feature in chrome for bandwidth limiting.